# how to get cakePHP Model->field method to use conditions with associated models?

Tags: model, cakephp-1.3, field, recursive-query, model-associations

I have a problem, I need to retrieve a single field from a single record, **without** the associated models, while using conditions that **uses** the associated models?

Example:

```
Categories {name, id}  
Keywords {name, id}  
Articles {title, text, id, keyword_id, category_id}
```

I want to retrieve the first `Articles.id` when `Article.category_id=3` etc.

Using `Model->field('model.field',array(conditions))` is working as long the conditions are not using the outer models. (`$this->Model->recursive=4` isn't working).

Using `Model->find('first', array(conditions))` works fine, except the fact that I get also the associated data that I don't need and don't want, limiting the recursion results with disabling the ability to use the associated models comparison..

any advice?

#### edit

my problem, except from being poor debugger :-) was solved by limiting the recursion while using the `model->read` method.
however, the long term is, probably, using the containable behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [find()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) method takes a `fields` argument as one of its options. You can also set the `recursive` argument to ensure you are getting the appropriate level of relationships.

Based on your OP, the following will retrieve what you want without joining any relationships.

```
$this->Article->find('first', array('recursive' => -1, 'fields' => array('Article.id'), 'conditions' => array('Article.category_id' => 3)));
```

If your requirements are stronger than the above, you can look at [binding models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly) or [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). But from what you described, the above is the appropriate solution. These would be overkill IMO.

Comment: (1) thanks, (2) I made a mistake here, was debugging the wrong line... (3) It won't work - since recursive=-1 will not allow conditions that uses associated models.

Comment: What's wrong with the normal level or recursion? Are you worried about the amount of relationships?

Comment: The number of records has nothing to do with the relationships. If you want to limit the amount of records, pass the `limit` attribute. Furthermore, `first` will only return 1 result. So you're doing something different than my recommendation.

Comment: again, the problem is not with model itself, it's the associated models that return the large amount of data

Comment: Given your model descriptions, the code above will not associate any models and only Article. Furthermore, it will return, at most, 1 result. I encourage you to edit your question with more details if you are still having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Model->find()` with the [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior to limit what associations are loaded and the field argument to limit the results only to the desired field.